# When the expectation maximum of N iid distributions is concave in N?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Assume there are $N$ iid random variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N$. I'm wondering that assumptions do we need to guarantee that 
$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(x_n)](N)
$$ 
is concave in $N$?

The expression I'm looking at is
$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(x_n)](N)=\int_x NF(x)^{N-1}f(x)\cdot x \,dx
$$ 
Seems that to make the function concave in $N$, we need the condition imposed on distribution $x\sim F(x)$.

Thanks in advance! Of course, it would be even better to have necessary and sufficient condition.

Many thanks to @Did in his answer. Here is how the result is proved.

Start from
$$
a(N)\equiv\mathbb{E}[\max \{x_n\}](N)=\int_x x dF(x)^N = \int_x x d(-(1-F(x)^N))
$$
Integration by part gives
$$
\mathbb{E}[\max \{x_n\}](N)=-(1-F(x)^N))|_0^\infty+\int_x (1-F(x)^N)dx=\int_x (1-F(x)^N)dx
$$

The concavity can be observed directly. 
And seems that the expression gives us an more general result which is
$$
\frac{\partial^m a(N)}{\partial N^m} = -\int_x F(x)^N (\ln F(x))^m dx
$$
So we has determined convexity or concavity of all orders of derivative.

Am I right? Let me know if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Did Thanks a lot! I add a few lines in my question. The result you mentioned can be a little generalized, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful formula for $$u_n=E(\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\})$$ for nonnegative i.i.d. random variables $(X_k)$ with CDF $F$, is $$u_n=\int_0^\infty P(\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}>x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty(1-F(x)^n)\,dx$$ For every $x$, the sequence $(F(x)^n)_n$ is convex, hence the sequence $(u_n)_n$ is indeed concave.

Comment: Really useful result. The proof is by integration-by-part?